# QuickFix on Windows with Python - Using MYSQL for events and messages

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, quickfix

Is this currently possible?
This is the contents of my settings.cfg file:

```
[DEFAULT]
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0SP2
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=60
FileStorePath=store
FileLogPath=*store

HttpAcceptPort=8080
HeartBtInt=30
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=00:00:00
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=quickfix/FIX50SP2.xml
TransportDataDictionary=quickfix/FIXT11.xml
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ResetOnLogout=Y
ResetOnLogon=Y

MySQLStoreDatabase=quickfix
MySQLStoreUser=user
MySQLStorePassword=password
MySQLStoreHost=ip address
MySQLLogDatabase=quickfix
MySQLLogUser=user
MySQLLogPassword=password
MySQLLogHost=0.0.0.0

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
SenderCompID=senderid
TargetCompID=targetid
SocketConnectPort=port
SocketConnectHost=host
```

Currently it is using the FileStorePath (/store/), but it is ignoring the MySQLStoreDatabase. Should I change these settings, or is the change going to be more complicated than that/impossible?

I'm using python 2.7 and quickfix 1.14.3 (which I installed using pip)

Comment: I should add that I installed quickfix using the wheel from here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix

Answer (score 2):

I bet you are constructing your app with a `FileStoreFactory`.

Gotta use a `MySQLStoreFactory`.

Comment: MySQLStoreFactory doesn't seem to be in the quickfix.py file, so I guess it's not included from {lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#quickfix}

Comment: I don't know much about the Python bindings, and even less about these unofficial bindings you're linking to.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the advice anyway....I've reposted this question with more specific wording [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393114/quickfix-on-windows-with-python-2-7-api-and-mysql-database)....not sure if that's allowed!

Comment: Having this issue here, did you find a solution?